# modifier private not allowes here

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, столкунулся с вопросом: есть класс "man"- public, его наследник "student". когда он без модификатора все работает, а когда ставлю к примеру private - пишет modifier private not allowes here, в чем проблема?
Вот код:

```
package l2;

public class Man {
    protected int age;
    protected double weight;
    protected String name, gender;
    protected Man (int age, double weight, String name, String gender) {
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}
protected int ageChanged (int n_a){
    age = n_a;
    return age;
}
protected double weightChanged (double n_w){
    weight = n_w;
    return weight = n_w;
}
protected String nameChanged (String n_n){
    name = n_n;
    return name;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student p1 = new Student (18, 67.3, "Anton", "male", 2016);
    Man p2 = new Man (45, 67.3, "Jack", "male");
    System.out.println("Возраст p1: "+p1.age+"; год обучения p1: "+p1.y_of_s+";");
    System.out.println("Возраст p2: "+p2.age+";");
    System.out.println("Возраст p1 (новій): "+p2.ageChanged (19)+"; год обучения p1 (новій): "+p1.y_of_sChanged (1)+";");
    System.out.println("Возраст p2 (новій): "+p2.ageChanged (46)+".");
}
}
class Student extends Man {
    protected int y_of_s;
    protected Student (int age, double weight, String name, String gender, int y_of_s){
    super (age, weight, name, gender);
    this.y_of_s = y_of_s;
}
protected int y_of_sChanged (int n_y_of_s){
    y_of_s += n_y_of_s;
    return y_of_s;
}
protected int ageChanged (int n_a){
    age += n_a;
    return age;
}
```

}

Comment: А можете добавить немного кода в вопрос? Что имеете и что пытаетесь сделать и что в итоге экспериментов получается.

Comment: У вас кусок кода вывалился из `...`

Comment: уже это исправил

Comment: @MuscledBoy
У меня программа отработала, вот результат:
`Возраст p1: 18; год обучения p1: 2016;

Возраст p2: 45;

Возраст p1 (новій): 19; год обучения p1 (новій): 2017;

Возраст p2 (новій): 46.
`

Comment: да, у меня тоже, я неправильно выразился. если я захочу поменять модификатор доступа к Student ошибку выбъет. и скажите можна оставить ли модификаторы дыные у полей или эти вполне подходят.

Comment: @MuscledBoy Чтобы это понять, достаточно положить  класс `Man` в один файл, а класс `Student` в другой, а `public static void main()` в третий, а потом смотреть при каких заработает. `Student` и `Man` по идее должны иметь модификатор доступа у конструктора `default` или `public`. У методов тоже, `public` или `default`. `private`,`protected` используются в основном, когда у класса есть внутренняя логика, которая снаружи быть доступна не должна. Допустим мы хотим печатать индекс тела для студента, тогда надо сделать `private` рост, вес, а функцию возвращающую индекс тела сделать `public`

Comment: а почему default или public? от задачи зависит?

Comment: `public` класс будет доступен из любого пекейджа, `default` только из этого же.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модификатор разрешает доступ внутри одного .java файла, если у вас разные файлы, первый класс имеет модификатор доступа `private`, то его наследник просто не сможет его увидеть. Если же сложить два класса в один файл, то вы можете менять их модификаторы как угодно, но из другого файла вы до этих классов не доберетесь, если у них не будет стоять модификатор `public` или `default(без модификатора, доступен внутри одного пекейджа)`
От самого закрытого до открытого строится так:
`private, default(без модификатора), protected,public`

Comment: то есть если у меня public у родителя, значит у наследника может быть только public? если я Вас правильно понял, а у меня и дефолтный тоже работает. это правильно?

Comment: Ошибся, не совсем правильно Вас понял, обновите страницу

Comment: дело в том, что оба класса в одном файле, компилится только при наследнике package

Comment: `public class Main {    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public class SampleClass {
        SampleClass() {
        }
    }

    private class ThisClass extends SampleClass {
        ThisClass() {
            super();
        }
    }
}`

Тоже самое что у Вас, у меня прекрасно компилируется

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь указать модификатор private/protected классу на верхнем уровне, а так по спецификации нельзя. Из Java Language specification:

> The access modifiers protected and private pertain only to member classes within a directly enclosing class declaration

Comment: Можете перевести вот этот ответ  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3491156/6104996  с ссылкой на него   )) Будет полезно

Comment: я только начал изучать java, скажите "высший уровень" это класс у которого являеться только наследником object?

Comment: Можно сказать и так